# I can't convert a JSON format file into a python format file

Tags: python, json

I'm doing pythonAPI exercises, and this is my completed API address：

http://api.juheapi.com/japi/toh?key=10245c2b75fa03d527204967ef7291cb&v=1.0&month=07&day=05

If you use the browser to open, the correct JSON file is displayed.but i cant't get correct 
result using the following codecode .

```
page = urllib.urlopen(url)
html = page.read() 
dic_json = json.loads(html)
print dic_json
```

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: sorry,please delete the address ]

Comment: like this:{u'reason': u'\u8bf7\u6c42\u6210\u529f\uff01', u'error_code': 0, u'result': [{u'des': u'\u5728602\u5e74\u524d\u7684\u4eca\u5929\uff0c1415\u5e747\u67086\u65e5 (\u519c\u5386\u516d\u6708\u521d\u4e00)\uff0c\u6377\u514b\u7684\u7231\u56fd\u4e3b\u4e49\u8005\u80e1\u53f8\u9047\u96be\u3002',

Comment: What is the wrong in this?? This is a dict type in python. I think you are saying that print statement is not showing the non-english letter, instead showing this `\u8bf7` type value?

Comment: @Swagat yes，I can not understand this

Comment: This is Unicode, when you print in console, it will be print like that for non-asic char

Comment: You wouldn't have this problem if you were using Python 3... You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: I tried it, seems to works fine. Cannot understand what is the issue here

Comment: @Swagat I think you mean "non-ASCII character".

Comment: Yes @PM2Ring, pardon my typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing error in the json. It successfully parse json to python dict. You should take a look on python [unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html). When you try to print a unicode in python 2 you will find like this, but when open in browser it will be correct non-ASCII character.

Python2 store non-ASCII character into like this format.

To read this particular dict , you can do something like this.

```
for x,y in dic_json.items():
    print x,":", y
```

Comment: Oh,okay,so,how I can print Unicode in console?

Comment: try with `print dic_json['reason']` , just for example